# What useful information could a post-post apocalyptic world glean from a 4chan-like resource?

Tags: culture, technological-development, post-apocalypse, communication, engineering

My post-post apocalyptic society (200+ years after the fall) is extremely technologically stratified, with the haves hoarding near-future technology and the have-nots making do with pre-industrial and very limited industrial tech. Enough knowledge has been lost that the fundamental concepts behind high-tech have effectively been lost, and apprenticeships begin to form around the maintenance/repair of these artifacts. Any remnants of the information age are long gone.

Enter: a trove of information similar to 4-chan, ie, a jumbled mess of political, technical, anarchic, meme-focused and borderline-edgelord content that often speaks in memetic 'code' and is not focused on teaching concepts at the tactile/applied level my people would be at (What qualities of corn would be best for ethanol? How do I repair/replace a semiconductor if I don't have scrap parts of this exact thing?).

My question: What could people with conceptual knowledge of industrial stuff (how and why a basic engine works, simple machines) and only applied knowledge of post-industrial stuff (electric stuff needs a battery, a computer can't think without the chips inside it) ...do with the information they'd find on 4-chan (defining 4-chan as it currently exists in 2018 (not the rest of the internet) and unable to be added-to afterwards) to better their lot?

Comment: Why would people need post 1990's information storage and technology in post-apocalyptic world? They either don't need it because they are focused on living or they have free time and can reinvent things on their own.

Comment: Social stratification in this setting is almost feudal, so I'm poking at this from the perspective of an iterant noble. They probably don't need it, but it is flashy and eye-catching.

Comment: If they're having trouble with a neighbouring tribe, they could copy the notorious "napalm shotgun" thread.

Comment: @F1Krazy That is exactly the kind of stuff I'm looking for.

Comment: @F1Krazy you don't need 4chan to get the knowledge on how to create mustard gas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the site itself, nothing. A good soul might try and pass on their engineering knowledge forward throught the network, but the nature of chan's, and the bad energy they have coagulated throughout the ages means that any sane discussion will be perverted within seconds.

A sample thread might go like this:

> Post 1: [Image of a wind turbine] Hello, fellow plainsdweller! In this tutorial I am going to teach you how to build an eolic generator with common the most common scrap found in the wasteland!
>
> Post 2: Windfag
>
> Post 3:
>   ▲
> ▲ ▲

However! Since a chan is acessible, it means there is some network infrastructure around. Some IT-minded engineer, a programmer even, might find out where the site storage is (if lucky, might be a CDN - Content Delivery Network, a way to cloud-host something globally). They might gain access to the server infrastructure and either rediscover, or found anew, the following stacks:

- Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault
- Engineering stack (https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)
- Home Improvement stack (https://diy.stackexchange.com/)
- Math Overflow (https://mathoverflow.net/)
- Physics (https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- Chemistry (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)
- Biology (https://biology.stackexchange.com/)

And last but not least, the most important site in the whole network:

- Coffee (https://coffee.stackexchange.com/)

In this way, our intrepid hero and their friends can help the world amass knowledge in a centralized reference base, sifting signal from noise and rewarding those who help rebuild the world with higher score and virtual medals.